# Здравствуйте, помогите решить задачу бинарным поиском на python

Tags: python, олимпиада, бинарный-поиск

Наткнулся на задачу:

Программа судей задумывает число N(1 ≤ N ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>). Ваша программа должна будет найти число, которое задуманное программой судей за максимум 100 запросов. В каждом запросе ваша программа входит в программу жюри “? X“(где X(1 ≤ X ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>) - целое число), в ответ на это программа жюри выведет значение (`X mod N`) в вашу программу.

При завершении ваша программа должна вывести число, которое задумали судьи в формате "! X"

Входные данные:
В ответ на каждый ваш запрос сделанный с помощью знака ? программа судей для данного вами числа X возвращает значение `X mod N`  соответственно.

Выходные данные:
Воспользовавшись максимум ста запросами найдите число, задуманное судьями.

Напоминание: Для того чтобы судьи могли принимать ваши ответы от интерактивной задачи в конце каждого запросы вы должны

```
Если используете язык ПАСКАЛЬ: `flush(output)`
Если используете язык C/C++: `fflush(stdout) или cout.flush()`
Если используете язык JAVA: `System.out.flush()`
Если используете язык PYTHON: `sys.stdout.flush()`
Если используете язык С#: `Console.Out.Flush()`
```

Использовать одну из вышеперечисленных команд!

Примеры

```
input.txt   output.txt
1           ? 10
2           ? 8
0           ? 4
0           ! 4
```

я пробовал решить вот так:

```
import sys
maxnumber = 10000000000
l = -1
k = maxnumber


print("? "+str(maxnumber))
sys.stdout.flush()
first = int(input())

while l+1<k:
    mid = int((l+k)/2)
    print("? "+str(mid))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    b = int(input())
    if b == 0:
        if (maxnumber-first)%mid == 0:
            print("!" + str(mid))
    else:
        k = mid
```

но получаю timelimit
Значит программа где-то не может пройти?

Comment: Что за единица в начале примера,откуда такие данные???   l не меняется, значит, цикл работает как `while k>0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экспоненциальный поиск с удвоением шага (n- загаданное число)

```
maxnumber = 10000000000
k = 1
n = 348

while True:   #while k < maxnumber:
    mod = k % n   #здесь запрос проверяльщикам должен быть
    print(k, mod)
    if mod < k:
        print('! ', k - mod)
        break
    else:
        k *= 2
```

Comment: Это не бинарный (двоичный) поиск. "Бинарный поиск" - термин, которым обозначают алгоритм при котором пространство поиска уменьшается в два раза на каждой итерации (подмассив уменьшается в два раза или отрезок на котором ищется корень функции). Этот алгоритм - поиск по степеням двойки, но не двоичный поиск.

Comment: Решение простое и изящное. Браво!

Comment: "@StanislavVolodarskiy `Exponential search extends binary search to unbounded lists...` обычно после этапа удвоения идёт уменьшение шага, здесь это не требуется. Ну да, просто бинарным называть это нехорошо

Comment: разобрался спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Задача решается в два запроса. К сожаление, это не двоичный поиск, но хоть что-то.

Первый запрос - максимальное значение *x<sub>1</sub> = 10<sup>9</sup>*. Пусть судья ответил *y<sub>1</sub>*. Тогда *x<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>1</sub> ≡ 0 (mod N)*. А *x<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>1</sub> - 1 ≡ N - 1 (mod N)*.

Второй запрос *x<sub>2</sub> = 10<sup>9</sup> - y<sub>1</sub> - 1*. Ответ *y<sub>2</sub>* будет равен *N - 1*. Окончательный ответ: *y<sub>2</sub> + 1*.

Небольшое улучшение: если оказалось что *x<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>* простое, его можно сразу объявить ответом. Второй запрос в этом случае не нужен.

С другой стороны можно показать что задача не может быть решена в один запрос для любых *N*. Следовательно, решение в два запроса является оптимальным.

```
x1 = 10 ** 9
print('?', x1, flush=True)
y1 = int(input())

x2 = x1 - y1 - 1
print('?', x2, flush=True)
y2 = int(input())

n = y2 + 1
print('!', n)
```